# pdf-tools-install takes a long time on startup

Tags: init-file, start-up, pdf-tools

I've installed pdf-tools through MELPA, and it works like a charm. Funnily, and as is documented in the [readme](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools), the command `pdf-tools-install` needs to be run each time if you want pdf-tools to be enabled; `(require 'pdf-tools)` is not enough (the use of the word "install" in the command name is a little bit misleading). The only thing is, it takes 12 seconds or so to run `pdf-tools-install` from my init.el file (clocked using `esup`).

So what I've done is the following:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'tex
  (pdf-tools-install)
  (setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "pdf-tools")))
  (setq TeX-view-program-list '(("pdf-tools" "TeX-pdf-tools-sync-view"))))
```

which allows it to only load when I'm in tex mode, which is nice. But it still means it takes an extra 12 seconds to load any tex file I want to work on, if I haven't loaded it in my current emacs session.

Call me impatient, but I literally moved to emacs from a more bloated editor in order to reduce startup times!! Is there any reason anyone can think of why it's taking so long to load `pdf-tools-install`, and a solution? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Because of discussions following this issue, I replaced `pdf-tools-install` with `(require 'pdf-tools)` in my init.el just to make sure that pdf-tools-install is indeed required, and it seems that it is. Using `(require 'pdf-tools)` does not properly initiate pdf-tools, and pdfs are displayed using the normal DocView mode, rather than pdf-tools' PDFView mode.

Comment: You only need to install pdf-tools once, not every time you open a tex file.

Comment: according to the [readme](https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools), pdf-tools-install needs to be in the init.el. When it is not, there is lots of missing functionality (synctex doesn't work, for instance)

Comment: I just checked, it just ends up reverting to docview instead of using PDFview without running pdf-tools-install.

Comment: Just run `pdf-tools-install` once and then put `(require 'pdf-tools)` in your init file.

Comment: @Dan, with `(require 'pdf-tools)`, startup time is still about 12 seconds, and fails to work; auctex reverts to docview.

Comment: Start emacs with no init file (emacs -Q) and try again. What you’re reporting is not normal behavior.

Comment: @Dan as this discussion shows the name `pdf-tools-install` is misleading, but it is the function that setups pdf-tools and must be added to init.el.  The slowness that @sacul experienced is caused by the search of a font that can display some unicode characters. In my answer I mention a variable that disables those characters, resolving the issue. A better solution is configuring the font so emacs don't have to search for it, but I'm too lazy to do it.

Comment: @matteol i only have the require statement in my init file and it works fine, so I don’t think the install function needs to be used repeatedly.

Comment: @Dan if I start `emacs -q` and execute `(package-initialize)` and `(require 'pdf-tools)` in the scratch buffer the pdf files are opened in DocView mode.

Comment: @matteol, I get the same behaviour. I've edited my question to clarify this, but in any case, your solution worked just fine, startup time is negligible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the variable `pdf-view-use-unicode-ligther` to nil, according to the doc it speeds up the loading on systems where looking for the unicode symbols used in the mode line (⎙ and ) takes a long time.

Comment: Amazing! That works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

After having pdf-tools installed (just once), put the following in your init file:

```
(add-hook 'doc-view-mode-hook 'pdf-tools-install)
```